# Apache HTTP Server slows down when image serving

Tags: apache, fileserver

My question is same as below:

https://serverfault.com/questions/295304/basic-apache-httpd-server-setup-becomes-slow-to-serve-images-requiring-frequent

Apache Server slows down while serving image frequently.Eventhough I setup and activate mpm_prefork_module.

I may install a webserver that paralells to Apache and serves only images (I come up with this paralell server idea.Do you suggest that?). I found varnish but My Server is on windows and Nginx is not free. What do you suggest me to use for image serving or What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx is free and open source, you can download here :

https://nginx.org/en/download.html

Mainline version

Could you provide more information ? (logs of apache)